# Image distortion after converting Numpy to PIL image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I want to convert some Numpy to Image, so I used the Image in PIL

```
from PIL import Image
im1 = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(X1)) # X1 dtype uint8, scale 0~255 image
im1.save("img.png")

im2= Image.fromarray(np.uint8(X2*255))   #X2 dtype uint16, sacke 0~1 mask ,so  X2*255
im2.save("mask.png")
```

X1, X2 are numpy arrays.
Then something confused happened. Some images look fine, but others disortion.

[image]
[image]

The first one is the disortion, the second is the normal.

Comment: These two are both images, and the mask look fine, so I don't display them.

Comment: The disortion appears in im1, the im2 which is binary mask look normal.

Comment: It would be easier for someone to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem.  We don't have, for example, `X1`.  Do you see the problem if `X1` is, say, `np.arange(256).reshape(16, 16).astype(np.uint8)`?

Comment: You could try [numpngw](https://pypi.org/project/numpngw/), a package that I wrote for writing numpy arrays to PNG files.  It has no other dependencies.

Comment: Try printing `np.amax(X1)` and likewise `np.amin(X1)` and likewise `X2`.

Comment: When I print np.amax(X1) in a for loop which display all images largest pixel，I find the problem. Most of the outpt is 255, but there are some very large number such as 3589. If I do a normalization before converting, distortion disappear. I shouldn't assume the pixels are all between 0-255 .

Answer (score 0):

Edited after reading *@Mark Setchell* comment: since PNG doesn't distort values, I guess they use JPG compression. If you want your image as is, try this:

```py
import cv2 

cv2.imwrite("img.png", img)
```

[Here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv2.imwrite) is the documentation.

Comment: PNG compression is lossless so turning it on or off, or changing its *quality* value will never distort the image values - it will only affect filesize and time to compress.